# Dynamically add/remove remote resources (JS, CSS) in JSFiddle widget

Tags: jsfiddle

Does anyone know if there's a way to dynamically add or remove resources (JS and CSS files) into a JSFiddle via the widget?

I basically want to be able to control which version o my CSS and JS files get loaded into a fiddle:

I know I can do this:

`<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/username/{{fiddleID}}/embed/js,html,css,resources,result/dark/"></script>`

but I am hoping for a way to do this:

`<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/username/{{fiddleID}}/embed/js,html,css,resources,result/file-{{version}}.css,file-{{version}}.js/dark/"></script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the creator:
No, embeddable is read-only:
https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues/981